# Why does $f$ is $C^2(\mathbb{R^n})$ bound below and $x$ in compact set imply Lipschitz Continuos Hessian

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, lipschitz-functions, hessian-matrix

I read in this [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6a7b/88a057f86f03ab07478e0677f0892d7b3121.pdf) that is about some numerical optimization method, that if $f$ is $C^2(\mathbb{R^n})$ and the iterates $x_k$ are in a compact set, then $\nabla^2 f$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition. The objective $f$ is furthermore assumed to be bound below in this set but no convexity assumption or similar is made.

Does anyone know, how this property comes about?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let $f(x)=|x|^{5/2}$. Then $f''(x)=\frac{15}4\sqrt{|x|}$ is not Lipschitz in any set containing $0$.

Comment: But it's not in $C^2$ either, is it?

Comment: As you can see, the second derivative is continuous, which means $C^2$. You either get the gradient Lipschitz or you need $C^3$ as assumption.